# Динамическое добавление методов к объекту в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, методы

Допустим у меня есть класс

```
class A:
    x, y = 1, 2
```

и объект для этого класса

```
a = A()
```

Как добавить к a новый метод?

Если сделать так

```
a.f = lambda self: self.x + self.y
print(a.f())
```

то получаю ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 8, in <module>
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

А если так

```
a.f = lambda: "body"
```

то внутри лямбда функции у меня нет доступа к объекту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance

```
import types

class A:
   x, y = 1, 2

a = A()
a.f = types.MethodType(lambda self: self.x + self.y, a)
a.f() # --> 3
```

Разница в следующем:

```
a.g = lambda self: self.x + self.y
a.f # --> <bound method A.<lambda> of <__main__.A object at 0x7f4de50d5978>>
a.g # --> <function <lambda> at 0x7f4de51babf8>
```

Но:

```
>>> A.h = lambda self: self.x + self.y
>>> a.h()
3
```